# gdallocationinfo is not recognized

Tags: gdal, fwtools

I tried to run **gdallocationinfo** from my FWTools shell and got a message saying: "gdallocationinfo is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file". So I checked the installation folder and didn't see any file with this name.

So I am guessing that something could be missing.
I've also tried to search for the file on Google but without success.
I am using FWTools 2.4.7 installed on Windows 7.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: FWTools is hopelessly out of date, and presumably predates this utility. Use OsGeo4W to replace your install with the gdal commandline tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [GDAL Wiki](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadingGdalBinaries):

> Important note: the FWTools binaries are not currently updated...

The GDAL/OGR version in FWTools is 1.7 from 2010.

I'm not sure when gdallocationinfo was included in GDAL, but it wasn't announced until late [2010](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506192530/http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-RFC-32-gdallocationinfo-utility-td3747218.html)

Try the [OSGeo4W](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/) or [GIS Internals](https://www.gisinternals.com/sdk.php) GDAL binaries instead.